# Gulp server stops whenever there's any error in a sass or js file

Tags: gulp

I'm a newbie at build systems so I used a sample gulpfile from Github as my guide for creating my own gulpfile (with some modifications). It was successful, but, lately, I noticed that whenever there's a single error in a sass or js file, gulp displays an error message and the server (browsersync server) stops.

Gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('assets/styles/sass/style.sass')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/styles/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('scripts', () => {
    return gulp.src('assets/js/src/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/build'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('serve', ['styles', 'scripts'], () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        },
        notify: false
    });

    gulp.watch('assets/styles/sass/style.sass', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('assets/js/src/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('index.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Is there a property or method that I should add to the `styles` task?

Answer (score 1):

Most people seem to use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) for this.  I would also modify your sass pipe to include error reporting ala

```
.pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
```

if you want to see a report on your sass errors.  Finally , I would modify the browserSync.stream pipe in 'styles' and 'scripts' to this:

```
.pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy :)